Convergence of a martingale that is a sum of differences of poisson r.v
The problem for context:
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and let $\left(\mathcal{F}_n\right)_{n \geqslant 0}$ be a filtration of $\mathcal{F}$. Consider a martingale $\left(M_n\right)_{n \geqslant 0}$ with respect to this filtration. We assume that the martingale satisfies the following condition for all $\boldsymbol{n}$ :
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[M_n^2\right] \leqslant C
$$
for some constant $C<\infty$.

Prove that $\left(M_n\right)_{n \geqslant 0}$ is uniformly integrable.
Show that $\left(M_n\right)_{n \geqslant 0}$ converges almost surely and in $L^1$ to a limit random variable $M_{\infty}$.
Now suppose that $M_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, where $X_i$ is the difference of two independent identically distributed (i.i.d.) Poisson random variables with parameter $\lambda$. Is $\left(M_n\right)_{n \geqslant 0}$ a martingale? Justify your answer.
If the answer to question 3 is affirmative, discuss the convergence of this sequence.
Provide an example of a martingale that does not converge.

Question
In question 4, after I find that it is indeed a martingale using the fact that the expectation of a difference of two i.i.d poisson random variables is null which at the end gives $E[M_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=M_n$ I can't apply something according to the first questions. I actually find that it diverge which seems wrong according to the previous questions.

Assuming independence of $(X_i)$ in 3) you can apply CLT to see that $(M_n)$ does not converge.

With the problem as stated, you are correct since
$$\mathbb E[M_n^2]=n\mathbb E[X_1^2]$$
which is unbounded, so you can't use the results that you have developed.
I agree that the way the question is posed suggests that you should be able to use your previous results to show convergence.
